# How to use string with phrases that contain spaces

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I used cin.getline after cin.ignore() but I am getting an error saying unassigned int... Not sure what to do or what is wrong. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cstring>

 using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
     string phras;
     cout << " Provide a phrase, up to 30 characters with spaces > " << endl;
     cin.ignore();
     cin.getline(phras, sizeof(phras));
     cout << " The phrase is: " << phras << endl;
     cout << endl;


     return 0;
 }
```

***UPDATE***
I changed cin.getline(phras, sizeof(phras));
to getline(cin,phras)
Problem solved! Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Why did you put code in the question that you don't want us to comment on? If it's not relevant, leave it out.

Comment: The `>>` operation to capture the single char will leave a newline char in the cin buffer. You can use `cin.ignore()` to remove it.

Comment: @paulRooney So I should write that before the cin >> letter or after? Sorry for the clarification question. I just want to make sure I do this right! Thank you by the way.

Comment: After `cin >> letter;` but before `cin.getline(word, sizeof(word));`. It will still screw up if you input more than one character at that point.

Comment: If anyone looks here for reference, this worked^^^. Adding cin.ignore()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
char letter[1];
```

isn't large enough. If a C string is to hold up to `N` characters, it needs to be declared `char letter[N+1]` to allow room for the null terminator character. So if the user is going to type a single character, it needs to be:

```
char letter[2];
```

As a result, you're getting undefined behavior when `cin >> letter` writes 2 characters into the array that only has room for 1.

Similarly, if the user is allowed to type a 10-letter word, it should be:

```
char word[11];
```

and it should be:

```
char phrase[31];
```

Comment: The first one is only supposed to hold ONE letter... If you read the statment before that it says enter one character..

Comment: @KatieStevers the compiler still sees `char letter[1];` as an array type. Perhaps you intended `char letter;`.

Comment: @KatieStevers Since it's a C string, you still need 2 elements to hold 1 letter. One for the letter, one for the null terminator.

Comment: Bammar, '0' is where you start counting not '1'. So no, 1 is correct. I just read this in '>>>> starting out with C++ From Control Structures through Objects' book .

Comment: However you do add an extra space for the null terminator '\0' or whatever it is. So it is at the end where that would effect things.

Comment: @KatieStevers When you declare an array, the size counts from 1. But when you index an array, the indexes start from 0 and go to size-1.

Comment: OHHHH! That makes since. Thanks for letting me know that!